# Thread.Sleep issue android methods and asynctask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am working on app that updates data for every 8 secs and the update was done using Async task. I am using loops to achieve this condition

```
while(const_val > update_val) {
new Asynctask().execute();
Thread.sleep(8000);
}
```

const_val  will be constant and will be not be changed by any other methods.lets say this value will be 5.update_val will be updated and decremented  when Asynctask  is called and let's the value will be 10. So , the while loop executes until the condition is true and asynctask ,sleep are called .

When I use above while loop in a general method then UI gets locked and if I use the same loop in another asynctask there was an error saying "Only original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its view "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you should use a surrounding loop.   Look at this example:

http://javatechig.com/android/progress-notification-in-android-example

- the AsyncTask is a private inner class
- the onPostExecute updates the UI with a message/cancels the load bar

This way you don't have to loop and the onCreate() can return instantly.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change your code to start the `AsyncTask` and have it provide an update via its `onPostExecute()` method.  By calling `Thread.sleep()` you are sleeping the main thread (or UI thread) of your app, which is not good.  You do not ever want to block the main thread.  This article may help you better understand `AsyncTask` and threading in Android: http://po.st/Cei3m2